# Using Azure Pipeline Environment Variables in Python Script

Tags: python, azure-devops

I declared variables on pipeline using user interface and when i try to reach it using `os.environ` it is unable to get. What am i missing?

Comment: You call the python script from the deployment yaml file?

Comment: I call it in a remote compute. Now I see why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note:

1. Azure Devops variables casing in bash is capital casing without dots i.e. Build.BuildId becomes BUILD_BUILDID, so make sure you are using correct casing as above - you can always see what environment variables are present by using print(os.environ)
   see here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#environment-variables
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline

2. Secret variables are not available as environment variables by default - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#user-defined-variables

I hope this help. Also variables in environment are available only on AZDO agents